# Why is DoneApplication not called from the Android RTL?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

In the implementation of `TApplication.Run` there is this:

```
{$IFNDEF ANDROID}
  AddExitProc(DoneApplication);
{$ENDIF}
```

Which means that `DoneApplication` is never executed on Android.

What is the reason for this variation between Android and all the other FireMonkey targets?

Comment: In the VCL in XE7 it's `{$IF NOT DEFINED(CLR)}`. In that case the call to `DontApplication` is handled in `TApplication.ProcessMessages`. Just to add some more wood on the fire. Perhaps it's supposed to be handled in the same way and was left out of `ProcessMessages` as an oversight.

Comment: The mobile platforms in Delphi use ARC so my guess is that they kept it that way when they ported the code. The big question (which you asked) is what is special about android. Why didn't they put something like `{$IFDEF AUTOREFCOUNT}` if it was because of ARC.